# Merge new array to state in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to do an infinite scrolling logic, I do this in `componentWillReceiveProps`, but did not see my list render correctly?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!isEqual(nextProps.listItems, this.state.listItems)){ //user scrolled, call next offset using the API
        this.setState({
            listItems: this.state.listItems.push(...nextProps.listItems)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spread both the current listItems and the next set of listItems in a new array to avoid mutating state.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!isEqual(nextProps.listItems, this.state.listItems)){ //user scrolled, call next offset using the API
        this.setState({
            listItems: [...this.state.listItems, ...nextProps.listItems]
        })
    }
}
```